# Borderlands Co-Op Lan Play - Guns and Ammo

Tags: borderlands

I have the PS3 version of this game, but I've never played online.  My friend and I are considering buying the PC version so we could play co-op on our PCs.

Can someone tell me how ammo and gun drops are handled in co-op?  Are they all 'free-for-all' or do we each get our own.  Does the distribution of ammo drops mean that my friend and I should avoid specializing in the same type of weapon (IE - shotgun) because we'd be fighting over the best shotgun weapons and ammo?

Also - can we both be the same character?  I thought the answer was no, but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loot is "first come first served": only one copy of each item exists for all players to share. This goes for both ammo, guns, shields, grenade mods, ... Everything. The only thing that is awarded "privately" for each player is quest rewards.

Not specializing in the same gun types *could* be beneficial, but I don't honestly think you'd have too much issues if you used the same kind of guns.

And yes - you can play the same class, if you so desire.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that some skills and items regenerate ammo.

Comment: Also worth noting that 'shared' = 'everyone gets the full amount', not 'divided equally'. I am not 100% on this though, only 99%, so I didn't edit your answer.

Comment: Not specializing in the same kinds of guns has advantages; as the solo Siren in most groups I get first dibs on elemental guns and leave non-elemental guns for others in 95% of cases. It really simplifies loot-sharing. Even if you're playing with cool people who can share it's nice to immediately know "Yeah, that gun's for Ben, but he'll be cool if I swipe this"